# How to find relationships in a large matrix with 1 and 0 values?

Tags: matrices

I'm looking for the mathematical algorythm used to determine the relationship between different columns in a very large matrix (Hundreds of columns) based on their 1/0 value in their rows.

Simplified example:

```
A|B|C|D
1|1|0|1
0|0|0|1
1|1|0|0
```

In this case A would report having a relationship with B and D. By relationship I mean that a is related to B and D because they all have 1s. But I want to calculate the "weight" of each relationship, in the example above the relationship between A and B is stronger (more lines) than A and D (only one line)

What I am looking for is something like this (not derived from the example above, just an illustration):
A: 20% B, 30%D

Thanks

Edit: 
After trying out multiplying the matrix with it's transpose, I am trying to figure out how to interpret the results:

```
A   B   C   D   E   F
1   0   0   1   0   0
0   1   1   0   0   1
0   0   0   0   1   0
```

multiplied by it's transpose:

```
1   0   0
0   1   0
0   1   0
1   0   0
0   0   1
0   1   0
```

Yields this result:

```
2   0   0
0   3   0
0   0   1
```

How could I read this result in terms of the columns in the original matrix above?

Comment: What do you mean by a 'relationship'?

Comment: So is it correct to say that: two columns are related if and only if they share at least one 1 in the same position?

Comment: Not quite, I need to get the weights calculated. see original post for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you multiply $A^T A$, the $ij$ entry of the result will tell you how many $1$s the $i$-th and $j$-th column have in common positions.

Comment: Tried an example for illustrative purposes. Having trouble reading the results, please see original post. thanks

Comment: In your example you multiplied $A A^T$ which counts common $1$s by rows, rather than $A^T A$ which will count by columns.